# How to use an event to change ellipse size?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, size, ellipse

I have the following problem:

I'm drawing two Ellipses on my UI. See this link: http://s14.postimg.org/6sajsb5tp/ellipse.png

I'm able to change its size by clicking on the blue line, but I only can change its size when the mouse is exactly on the line, otherwise I cannot.

My question is:

How can I set a tolerance, I mean .. Is there any event that I can use to set an amount of pixels, lets say 20 pixel, to know when the mouse is close to the blue line?

I did it mathematically on every MouseMove event, but I wonder if .. is there a better way? :)

Thanks.

**[Edit1]**

I tested @J... approach but it takes about 20 ms to give an answer if the mouse is close to the line or not, I find it slow so I'll keep with my approach, where on every canvas event `MouseLeftButtonDown` I check the mouse position in relation with my center Ellipse coordinates. It takes only 0.05 ms to check.

Thanks for helping guys.

Comment: @J... thank you! .. I couldn't find any related topic =\

Answer (score 0):

I would think a better way to is to drop your elispse in a container and then attach your event handler to the container.